# array of even, odd, and negative integers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to:

Write a program that takes 10 integers as input. The program places the even integers into an array called evenList, the odd integers into an array called oddList, and the negative integers into an array called negativeList. The program displays the contents of the three arrays after all the integers have been entered.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testsheeeyt {

    public testsheeeyt() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int evenList[] = new int[10];
    int oddList[] = new int[10];
    int negativeList[] = new int[10];
    int neg =0;
    int odd = 0;
    int even =0;
    int x=0;

    System.out.println("Enter number ");
    for(x= 0;x<10;++x){     



        if(x%2 == 0 && x>0){
            evenList[x] = scan.nextInt();
            even++;
        } 
        if(x%2 != 0){
            oddList[x] = scan.nextInt();
            odd++;
        }if(x<0){
            negativeList[x] = scan.nextInt();
            neg++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("The list of negative numbers is :-"); 
    for (x = 0; x < neg; x++) 
    { 
    System.out.println( negativeList[x]); 
    } 
    System.out.println("\nThe list of even numbers is :-"); 
    for (x = 0; x < even; x++) 
    { 
    System.out.println( evenList[x]); 
    } 
    System.out.println("The list of odd numbers is :-"); 
    for (x = 0; x < odd; x++) 
    { 
    System.out.println( oddList[x]); 
    }

    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

it won't work. help.

Comment: What error are you getting? What have you tried? Can you please post a little bit more information so we know where to look.

Comment: `"it won't work"` doesn't give us much information that we can use to help you. Please provide more details on your problems and your question.

Comment: @Winston: please don't use code spans (`like this`) to highlight text -- it should only be used for code within sentences. For example, `x % 2 != 0` is okay, but `integers` should not be in a code span. Thanks!

Comment: my arrays arent under the correct categories and i'm getting a lot of 0's in the final result. negative usually never work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you want your input loop to look something like this -

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
  System.out.println("Enter number: " + (x + 1));
  int num = scan.nextInt(); // <-- get user input to
                            // test.
  // Test for negative first.
  if (num < 0) {
    negativeList[neg++] = num;
  } else {
    // It isn't negative.
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      // It is even.
      evenList[even++] = num;
    } else {
      // It must be odd.
      oddList[odd++] = num;
    }
  }
}
```

Second, here is one method for output

```
// Are there any negative numbers?
if (neg > 0) {
  System.out.println("The negative numbers are: ");
  for (int x = 0; x < neg; x++) {
    if (x != 0) {
      // Add a comma between entries.
      System.out.print(", ");
    }
    // Print the number at x (where x is 0 to neg).
    System.out.print(negativeList[x]);
  }
  // Add a new line.
  System.out.println();
}
```

Another way to print arrays (if they're correctly sized) is to use [Arrays#toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) -

```
 System.out.println("The negative numbers are: " + Arrays.toString(negativeList));
```

Comment: I'm starting to understand. I now can determine if it's a negative and show those numbers (per your code) but I also need to figure out how to show the even and odd values.

{
  System.out.println("The even numbers are: ");
  for (int x = 0; x < even; x++) 
   {
   if (x % 2 =! 0) 
   {
   System.out.print(", ");
  } 
   System.out.print(evenList[x]);
  }
  System.out.println();


didnt work

Comment: You need `if (x != 0)` instead of `(x % 2 =! 0)` which probably gives you a compiler error. Otherwise, that looks right.

Answer (score 0):

you need check input number not x.
like

```
for(x=0;x<10;++x){
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    if(t>=0){
        if(t%2 == 0 ){
            evenList[x] = t;
            even++;
        } else{
            oddList[x] = t;
            odd++;
        }
    }else {
        negativeList[x] = t;
        neg++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are lopping through `x` from one to ten.

If `x` is odd you put the input into the odd array even if it is even 
If `x` is evev you put the input into the even array even if it is even

You want to get the input and see if the input is odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the loop indices with x and it is this number which you are checking whether is even, odd, or negative. If I understand the question right, you need to process the input numbers. Try the following:

```
for(x= 0;x<10;++x){     
int num = scan.nextInt();
    if(num%2 == 0 && num>0){
        evenList[x] = num;
        even++;
    } 
    else if(num%2 != 0){
        oddList[x] = num;
        odd++;
    }else if(num<0){
        negativeList[x] = num;
        neg++;
    }
}
```